# pool.connect (PG) and db.query (PG_PROMISE) suddenly takes 20 seconds to execute?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, pg-promise

Setup: Windows 10 with postgresql v. 11.8 installed locally on the laptop.
NodeJS: 12.17 LTS

Both frameworks PG and PG-PROMISE are both great - BUT in our developing team we all experience the same issue from time to time: That suddenly something gets stuck and a simple query takes 20 secs to execute!?

Current solution: We restart our machines when it happens (which of course is pretty annoying when you are in the middle of a flow ;-) )

1. NPM module PG: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Code (I have earlier reported this issue: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2206):
(and yes - I know you ([charmander](https://github.com/charmander)) now have marked the issue as "Need more info" - But I simply can't because it happens every-every-other-day, on different machines and without we install something new, update other modules etc.)

```
console.time('timer1');
const client = await pool.connect();
console.timeEnd('timer1');
```

2. I replaced the NPM PG modules with PG-PROMISE: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise

> ```
> const Promise = require('promise');
>     const initOptions = {
>         promiseLib: Promise
>     };
>
>     const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
>
>     const cn = {
>         host: process.env.PGHOST,
>         port: process.env.PGPORT,
>         database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
>         user: process.env.PGUSER,
>         password: process.env.PGPASSWORD
>     };
>
>     const db = pgp(cn);
> ```

...

```
db.query(query, params).then(result => {
if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result !== null)
    resolve(result);
else
    resolve();
})
.catch(error => {
    _wl.error(error, 'sqlquery error:'); // _wl = Winston logger
    reject(error);
})
```

Comment: That's probably not the only example of accessing database in your code, and since this code doesn't show any problem, the issue is in some other place that you are not showing here.

Comment: 1. I only have one single API which all my projects use to access the db :) 2. When I can measure that: const client = await pool.connect(); takes 20 secs when I experience the issue I don't know where or what else to look for...if you have any idea - please tell me :)

Comment: What version of pg-promise are you using? Could be an old issue.

Comment: As mentioned in the GitHub issue version: 8.0.3 (It was the latest version at that time being ~ 24 days ago). But yes - I see now that 3 releases have been released since (you are working fast! :-D )... Do you know if the current and latest version 8.2.1 should fix this?

Comment: I use the following versions now: 8.2.1 (used to be 8.0.3) of PG and 10.5.6 of PG-PROMISE

Comment: we are having exactly the same issue, its driving us mad, and its causing outages, in our case we havent tested pg-promise yet. but in our case the service will run fine for days, and all of a sudden queries start timing out. we thought at first it was the db, or network infrastructure of where the containers were. Then another batch service started having the exact same issue, after a couple of days in our case we are using 8.2.1.
This is driving us made, because we cant reproduce it locally. also we only use pg.connect to listen to triggers, otherwise pool.query.

Comment: @PabloDK did switching to pg-promise fixed the issue? also did u try to use pool.query instead before switching?